# Is there any methods available other than brute force and dictionary attacks?

Tags: attacks, brute-force, password-cracking, dictionary

I am curious to know about the wifi attacks. And I have known a little bit about brute force attack and dictionary attack. Is there any other methods available other than these two...?

Comment: What Wi-Fi protocol are you talking about? There are several fatal attacks against WEP, and there is also a very damaging attack against WPA (and WPA2 with TKIP), both exploiting their use of RC4, which don't exist for WPA2 with CCMP.

Answer (score 1):

To attack a black-box (i.e. you don't have access to the hashes), then you will be mostly limited Brute-Force and Dictionary Attacks. If you manage to get the hashes in question, then you can also perform a [Rainbow Table Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

There is also an entire group of attacks known as [Side Channel Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack). However these are often very specific to an implementation, rather than a general attack.